# How to get live data (output, progress) from a powershell job?

Tags: powershell, start-job

I know I get a job's output when calling Receive-Job. But as you can see with `Get-Job | Format-List -Property *`, jobs jave a lot of properties, most of them seem to be unused.
I want to track progress and maybe some errors, but how do I pass some data to the Progress, Output and Error properties from within the job?

Comment: This article may help. https://dille.name/blog/2015/09/11/displaying-progress-from-powershell-jobs/ When you have code you are trying to make work, copy and paste it into the question along with a description of what it is doing and what the desired result is. Until then, it is not really a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Receive-Job cmdlet
The Receive-Job cmdlet gets the results that have been generated by the time that the Receive-Job command is
    submitted. If the results are not yet complete, you can run additional Receive-Job commands to get the remaining
    results.

I would recommand to read about it more with:

```
get-help Receive-Job
```

Also, please note that when you run the Receive-Job, it will **remove** the results after showing it. **If you want to keep them**, you will have to use the **-Keep** Switch

Powershell can't show you progress of the job natively, and you will have to find other ways.. you can use the Receive-Job to see what is already done.

let me know if it helped you.